# Jquery Display Div with Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to hide several divs one by one or with a time interval of 5 seconds, i tried below doesn't seem to work though

```
<div id="container">
<div id="data1">123</div>
<div id="data2">456</div>
<div id="data3">789</div>
<div id="data4">012</div>
</div>
<script>

$('document').ready(function(){
     window.setTimeout('mytimer()',5000);
  });
$('document').ready(function(){
     window.setTimeout('mytimer2()',10000);
  });

$('document').ready(function(){
     window.setTimeout('mytimer3()',15000);
  });

$('document').ready(function(){
     window.setTimeout('mytimer4()',20000);
  });


  function mytimer(){   $('#data1').hide();    } 
  function mytimer2(){   $('#data2').hide();    } 
  function mytimer3(){   $('#data3').hide();    } 
  function mytimer4(){   $('#data4').hide();    } 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use single timeout function as your are hiding at regular intervals. There is one mistake in your code you need to pass the *reference* of function to `setTimeout` instead of passing the function call as a string.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Le86g5og/)

```
window.setTimeout(mytimer,1000);
index = 1;
function mytimer()
{     
     $('#data' + (index++)).hide();
     if(index <= 4) window.setTimeout(mytimer,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(document)` instead of `$('document')`

`$('document')` will look for HTML Element with `document` tag, which doesn't exist.

Learn to use developer tools, Here's a good read: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

*Code*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     window.setTimeout(mytimer,5000); //You can simply pass the function reference 
     window.setTimeout(mytimer2,10000);
     window.setTimeout(mytimer3,15000);
     window.setTimeout(mytimer4,20000);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(mytimer, 5000);
    window.setTimeout(mytimer2, 10000);
    window.setTimeout(mytimer3, 15000);
    window.setTimeout(mytimer4, 20000);
});
function mytimer(){
    $('#data1').hide();
}
function mytimer2(){
    $('#data2').hide();
}
function mytimer3(){
    $('#data3').hide();
}
function mytimer4(){
    $('#data4').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `.delay()` in jquery** . No Settimeout function needed.

```js
$('#data1').delay(5000).hide('fast');
$('#data2').delay(10000).hide('fast');
$('#data3').delay(15000).hide('fast');
$('#data4').delay(20000).hide('fast');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="data1">123</div>
<div id="data2">456</div>
<div id="data3">789</div>
<div id="data4">012</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change and so on for the rest:

```
window.setTimeout(mytimer, 5000);// removed quotes and `()`
```

Another solution using jQuery fadeOut():

```js
$(function() {
  for (var i = 1; 4 >= i; i++)
    $('#data' + i).fadeOut(5000 * i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="data1">123</div>
  <div id="data2">456</div>
  <div id="data3">789</div>
  <div id="data4">012</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `setInterval` function too for this and once all the elements have been `hidden` you can `clearInterval` like one below:

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/97bvks5b/)**

```
function mytimer(elem){   
    console.log('came here');
    $(elem).hide();    
} 

$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    var interval=null;
    interval = window.setInterval(function(){
         i++;
         if(i<=$('#container').children().length)
             mytimer("#data"+i);
        else
        {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
    },5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code.

1. You have used `$('document').ready(function(){})`, which is incorrect. `document` is a keyword, it shouldn't be in quotes.
2. You don't have to use multiple instance of calling `$(document).ready()`. You can call all your statements from a single function. You can also use `$(function(){})`.
3. While calling the function name inside the timeout function, you shouldn't put them under quotes. They act like keywords after you have defined them in your code. The function call inside the Timeout function shouldn't be followed by `()`. So it should be `window.setTimeout(mytimer,5000);`

Please refer the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/65gs8s9y/

I have modified your code which works fine now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(mytimer,5000);
    window.setTimeout(mytimer2,10000);
    window.setTimeout(mytimer3,15000);
    window.setTimeout(mytimer4,20000);
  });

  function mytimer(){   
      $('#data1').hide();    
  } 
  function mytimer2(){   
      $('#data2').hide();    
  } 
  function mytimer3(){   
      $('#data3').hide();    
  } 
  function mytimer4(){   
      $('#data4').hide();    
  }
```